# The method creator(PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber, String) is undefined for the type Message

Tags: java, twilio

sdk i'm using- twilio-java-sdk-7.0.0-rc-10-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
I'm working on eclipse luna and ibm bluemix is the server.
the code-

```
String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACa0c22e33e95dcaf9a0b1370748855769";
String AUTH_TOKEN = "[auth-token]"; //pasted the correct token here
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

     Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+91"+rsa.getString(2)),
                    new PhoneNumber("+12014904147"), 
                    "Congrats, "+rsa.getString(3)+"! Your booking for the event has been confirmed. You will be contacted by the event representatives soon.")
                    .create();
```

the error- The method creator(PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber, String) is undefined for the type Message.
I try to solve this error by replacing creator with create. The arguments are of type (String,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumber,String). I'm not sure what the first String is for.
Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: What does the documentation *say* it's for?

Comment: have you imported the correct Message class? Looking at the javadoc there are 4 Message classes in 4 different packages. https://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/7.0.0/index.html

`com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message` appears to have the `creator(PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber, String)` method.

Comment: @JonK couldn't find in documentations. They're using creator everywhere. Tried other methods too but no luck.

Comment: my import statement is like- 
    import com.twilio.sdk.resource.api.v2010.account.Message;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 6 classes called `Message` in Twilio. See the [Javadoc](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/7.11.0/index.html).

You need to figure out which one to use and add an `import` statement that imports the right one.

You probably want to `import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;` as this Message class has a `creator` method that fits your invocation:

```
static MessageCreator creator(PhoneNumber to, PhoneNumber from, String body)
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed the jar file and modified the imports and it finally worked!